# How to delete a misspelled directory?

Tags: git

I've edited a README.md from my project with `stackedit`.

When I select "publish" on git (it then commit directly), I've set the path to:

`./README.md`

It work... but not as I expected.  Indeed, it create a `.` repository on my project (I suppose with the file inside).
But now I can't remove it.

I've reported the issue to stackedit (see https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/405) without any success.

Any idea?

---

Here is the output with `git rm`:

```
$ cd ~/mgd
$ git rm '.'
fatal: not removing '.' recursively without -r
$ git rm -r '.'
rm '.gitignore'
rm 'LICENSE'
rm 'README.md'
rm 'TODO.md'
rm 'ez_setup.py'
rm 'setup.py'
rm 'src/mgd/__init__.py'
rm 'src/mgd/readers/__init__.py'
rm 'src/mgd/readers/manga_reader.py'
rm 'src/mgd/readers/registre.py'
rm 'src/mgd/store.py'
rm 'src/mgd/util.py'
rm 'test/mgd/test_store.py'
$
```

The `.` dir was not removed...

---

The ls output:

```
$ ls
LICENSE  README.md  TODO.md  ez_setup.py  setup.py  src  test
$ ls -al
total 37
drwxr-xr-x    1 abz      Administ     4096 May 19 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 abz      Administ    32768 May 19 11:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 abz      Administ     4096 May 19 11:56 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 abz      Administ      544 May 19 11:56 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 abz      Administ    11323 May 19 11:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 abz      Administ     1574 May 19 11:56 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 abz      Administ      387 May 19 11:56 TODO.md
-rwxr-xr-x    1 abz      Administ    15757 May 19 11:56 ez_setup.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 abz      Administ     1276 May 19 11:56 setup.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 abz      Administ        0 May 19 11:56 src
drwxr-xr-x    3 abz      Administ        0 May 19 11:56 test
$
```

---

What I've done:

1. `$ git rm -rf *` remove all files / directory
2. `git checkout -- *` get all files but **not** `.` directory
3. enjoy

   $ git status
   [...]
   deleted:    ./README.md

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried `git rm`?

Comment: Answer in the main message.

Comment: Which OS is that? Windows or Linux?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: The standard `rm` command does not remove the current directory, `.`, so why should `git rm -r .` do it any differently?  Besides, if there's no content in the directory, it won't survive in the repository (though it still exists in the checked out area).

Comment: There is content (well.. normaly...) because the file path was `./README.md`.
But because the `.` is a special directory I can't "get in".

Comment: @Djab: How do you know it created a `.` directory? Which command lets you see this "folder"?

Answer (score 1):

`.` and `..` are automatic folders which are created by Linux file systems. Git can neither create nor delete them. In fact, Linux will emulate those folders for file systems which don't support them.

So `./README.md` and `README.md` are the same file. You can test this with `cp ./README.md README.md`

**[EDIT]**
Now Git is a slightly different beast since it emulated it's own file system inside of `.git/objects`. At the same time, Git does interface with the OS. So if you tell Git to remove `./README.md`, then Git will notice "oh, there is folder" so it will first "cd" into `.` (the one in the real file system, not the one inside of Git's virtual file system) and then it will delete the correct `README.md`.

What we need would be a way to tell Git: "Just do this in your virtual file system." For this, you need to dig into [Git internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Behind the link, you'll find an explanation how the internal structure works and how to access the trees and objects directly, bypassing the front end commands which will mix internal and external paths.

When unraveling the mess, you will start with the commit object ([explained here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects)) since you know its hash (`15a0ec6aee0ae08764623a304e3fc5ce96cef821`) and it contains the hash of the tree. The tree object probably contains the illegal name.

It would be interesting to know which command `stackedit` used to create such an illegal file name. Maybe it's using a normal Git frontend command

Comment: Well.. Yes and no. If you take a look to these version: https://github.com/Djabx/mgd/tree/15a0ec6aee0ae08764623a304e3fc5ce96cef821 you can see the `.` directory and the `README.md`is not the one commited.
So for git ? github ? it's not the same file.

Comment: Ah. The illegal filename probably ended up in the tree object. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks @AaronDigulla ! I will read this for better understanding ! Is it bug ? Should I report a bug ?

Comment: It's definitely a bug but I can't say whether its in `stackedit` or `git`.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the dot directory you are talking about is in this [repo](https://github.com/Djabx/mgd/tree/master/) then I think you should do `git rm -fr "\\.` and then delete the directory manually if still exists: `rm "\\."` since git doesn't track empty directories.